# Mobile App shows no ads and why am I not listed in google's sellers.json?

Tags: android, mobile, expo, admob

I use Google AdMob to show ads on my mobile app and I am not listed in the sellers.json. I think this is the reason why my released mobile App does not show ads. The technical implementation is correct, someone at google mobile sdk confirmed that. They also said I get a no fill error and I should check with Google AdMobs. Then I read up and checked the seller.json file under http://realtimebidding.google.com/sellers.json and my pub id is not in the list.

My Admob, AdSense and Google Ads accounts are set up fine, I have no policy issues and filled out every respective field I could. My app is released since almost one month now in Googles Play Store. No issues there too.

I did already a really time consuming check-writeup of many potential issues which would be to much for this post here, but can be looked up [here](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/186356502/ads-not-showing-anymore-in-production-app-worked-fine-until-a-few-days-ago)

I tried many times to speak directly to a Google AdMob contact person, but the contact Email page always shows "Something went wrong" error since many days. Otherwise I see no way to get help apart from the community, which turned out also not very helpful.

Does anyone know what the reason can be not seeing my pub-id in the sellers.json? Where can I check, whom can I contact?

This is my last resort here, many thanks.

Comment: `sellers.json` is for "currently listed premium publishers using Google Ad Manager" from https://support.google.com/authorizedbuyers/answer/9895942?hl=en# so if you were in that program, you wouldn't be asking on SO. Also low install numbers (5?) means that the ad algo will not send ads to your app (10K ad impressions for a popular app vs 10 for a seldom used app) but that is all on the Google side. As you appear to have gotten ads early, which means the ad SDK was setup correctly, so there is nothing actionable or on-topic here on SO and you should look to Android dev forums or discord.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your quote from the link says one sentence later "AdMob and AdSense publishers are also included". I use admob like said and I'm sure my pub id has to be in the sellers.json. My brother uses admob too, like me, he is listed in sellers.json, has 100+ installs and gets ads. Not showing ads just because the app has not many installs makes absolutely no sense imho, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Ah I stand corrected, found: https://www.adexchanger.com/publishers/google-grows-its-sellers-json-file-to-1-2-million-publishers/ but still the issue is on Google's side and still not appropriate/actionable as a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Google AdMobs contact form on their help site does not work. There is an error since weeks. Community does not give answers. I know stackoverflow is not the place to ask this but what should I do then?